# Пакет не скачивается, ошибка!

Tags: kali-linux

Я пытаюсь скачать пакет pip:

sudo apt-get install python-pip

Но после этого выдает ошибку :

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Что делать? Какие пакеты нужно удалить?